# Creating a D365 view filtered by lookup

Tags: filter, view, lookup, crm, dynamics-365

Is it possible to create a view in Dynamics365 where records are filtered, based upon a separate list (lookup) of account IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

A view is a customization component of a table.

1. Open the solution your table is part of and select `Tables` => `Views`.
2. In the menu bar select `Add view`.
3. In the pane on the right select `Edit filters ...`.
4. In the dialog select `+ Add` => `Add related table`.
5. Select the referencing column and add conditions as needed. You have numerous options.